# Help on Illegal assignment from List in Apex

Tags: apex, apexrest

How can i place below data Into Map :

```
(
        caseInfoWrapper:
        [carrierId=, 
        partyId=a1K2F000000lWJrUAM, 
        product=SI, 
        productType=Whole Life, 
        stateId=AK]
)
```

And

```
global class NewCtr {
public static List<caseInfoWrapper> caseInfoWrapperRecords(List<ATD_Application__c> applicationList,Id partyId){
      List<caseInfoWrapper> lsCaseWrappers = new List<caseInfoWrapper>();
        for(ATD_Application__c caseInfo : applicationList){
            caseInfoWrapper wrapper = new caseInfoWrapper();
            wrapper.partyId = caseInfo.Party__c;
            wrapper.productType = 'Whole Life';
            lsCaseWrappers.add(wrapper);
            system.debug('lsCaseWrappers***'+lsCaseWrappers);
        }
        return lsCaseWrappers;
    }
    
    }

global class caseInfoWrapper{
    global String partyId;
    global String productType;
      
} 
    
global with sharing class NewHandler {

    list<caseInfoWrapper> wrapperRecords = NewCtr.caseInfoWrapperRecords(applicationList,partyId);
}
```

when calling abouve method in NewHandler class ,    getting below error :

```
Illegal assignment from List<NewCtr.caseInfoWrapper> to List<String>
```

Thanks
VRK

Comment: Can you paste the caseInfoWrapper class?

Comment: Thanks for your response ....Just updated code , pls check

Comment: global class caseInfoWrapper{
        global String partyId;
        global String productType;
          
    }

Comment: i am unable to modify code, this is wrapper class......i am unable to call this class in another Class.....thanks

Comment: I don't see any assignments in this code that could throw that error. Could you please make sure the exact line of the error is included here and clearly identify it? In general, type errors mean _exactly_ what they say - you cannot assign a list of wrappers to a list of strings, so one of them is wrong.